# How to draw a baloon shape in android?

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

Is it possible to create a drawable like on the picture below using `<shape>` tag in Android?[image]

UPD: the goal is to draw these baloons on a `MapView`. Is there a standart component for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's a regular 9patch picture (.9.png). No way you can create that using only shapes.

Map markers are usually done by implementing an ItemizedOverlay class. Check out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard component for drawing balloons.  I am pretty sure that graphing cam from here:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Just use that code.